# On webapps.stackexchange.com, the protected question banner overlaps the "Not the answer you're looking for'?" banner

Tags: bug, design, protected-questions

This is the same on all protected questions:

[image]

The top of all tall letters (`N`,`t`,`h`,`'`,`l`,`k`,`f`,`B`,`d` - in order) are overlapping the yellow box.

This is a zoomed in image.

[image]

Page Examples [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22291/turning-off-google-search-results-indirection) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41591/alternatives-for-google-reader-with-android-synchronizing), in fact all protected questions.

NB: I am not logged in for these screenshots, but there is the same problem when I am.

Comment: Same problem with the bounty banner, apparently: [Web Applications Meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2671).

Comment: @Fish thanks! Have flagged my post on there as a dupe.